# Proper way to handle long running cleanup logic in response to Netty channelInactive event?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, completable-future

I have a Netty application that keeps track of connected web socket connections. When a web socket disconnects, I need to perform some logic that cleans up the stored data on that connection. I'm trying to be a good Netty citizen and not block the event loop with this cleanup logic, so I'm running everything in a `CompletableFuture`. The logic looks vaguely like this:

```java
  @Override
  public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    String connectionId = ctx.channel().id().asLongText();
    LOGGER.info("Web socket disconnected: {}.", connectionId);
    connectionStore
        .deleteConnection(connectionId)
        .thenCompose(
            (connection) → {
              LOGGER.info("Deleted connection {}, publishing event.", connectionId);
              return messageBusPublisher.publish(new DisconnectEvent(connectionId));
            })
        .thenAccept((v) -> LOGGER.info("Done cleaning up connection {}.", connectionId));
  }
```

This results in log statements like this:

```
2020-02-10 17:47:23,091 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-2] INFO  c.e.WebSocketFrameHandler - Web socket disconnected: acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000004-d86b4b1c219b503a-d8239aa2.
2020-02-10 17:47:23,091 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-2] INFO  c.e.store.ConnectionStore - Attempting to delete connection for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000004-d86b4b1c219b503a-d8239aa2
2020-02-10 17:47:23,092 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-1] INFO  c.e.WebSocketFrameHandler - Web socket disconnected: acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000003-60f2c3402164ad79-a7e03a19.
2020-02-10 17:47:23,092 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-1] INFO  c.e.store.ConnectionStore - Attempting to delete connection for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000003-60f2c3402164ad79-a7e03a19
2020-02-10 17:47:23,093 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-3] INFO  c.e.WebSocketFrameHandler - Web socket disconnected: acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000005-6962838a219b52e9-e6ceac8b.
2020-02-10 17:47:23,093 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-3] INFO  c.e.store.ConnectionStore - Attempting to delete connection for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000005-6962838a219b52e9-e6ceac8b
2020-02-10 17:47:23,093 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-5] INFO  c.e.WebSocketFrameHandler - Web socket disconnected: acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000007-ccfcc4a5219b57eb-d78fc5f5.
2020-02-10 17:47:23,093 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-4] INFO  c.e.WebSocketFrameHandler - Web socket disconnected: acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000006-6c933ab1219b554f-2b3cf759.
2020-02-10 17:47:23,093 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-5] INFO  c.e.store.ConnectionStore - Attempting to delete connection for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000007-ccfcc4a5219b57eb-d78fc5f5
2020-02-10 17:47:23,093 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-4] INFO  c.e.store.ConnectionStore - Attempting to delete connection for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000006-6c933ab1219b554f-2b3cf759
2020-02-10 17:47:23,097 [lettuce-kqueueEventLoop-4-1] INFO  c.e.store.ConnectionStore - Successfully deleted connection for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000004-d86b4b1c219b503a-d8239aa2
2020-02-10 17:47:23,102 [lettuce-kqueueEventLoop-4-1] INFO  c.e.WebSocketFrameHandler - Deleted connection acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000004-d86b4b1c219b503a-d8239aa2, publishing event.
2020-02-10 17:47:23,127 [lettuce-kqueueEventLoop-4-1] INFO  c.e.service.MessageBusPublisher - Attempting to publish message for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000004-d86b4b1c219b503a-d8239aa2
2020-02-10 17:47:23,866 [sdk-async-response-0-0] INFO  c.e.service.MessageBusPublisher - Successfully published message for acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000004-d86b4b1c219b503a-d8239aa2
2020-02-10 17:47:23,866 [sdk-async-response-0-0] INFO  c.e.WebSocketFrameHandler - Done cleaning up connection acde48fffe001122-000080ec-00000004-d86b4b1c219b503a-d8239aa2
```

The problem I'm running into is that when multiple disconnects happen in short order, it seems that the full cleanup logic is only run for the first one or two connections, and beyond that, nothing after the initial call is processed. This means the connections are properly deleted from the store, but no follow up actions are processed beyond that. My assumption is that this is because the `CompletableFuture` that represents the full chain of calls is not bound to anything, so when the first calls in the chain complete, the callbacks are not executed.

I've tried various things like using `ctx.channel().eventLoop().execute(...)` to run the clean up code (and theoretically bind the execution to the channel's event loop), but I see the same results.

My question then is: what is the appropriate way to fire off I/O bound tasks in response to Netty channel events?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. channelInactive(...) should be called for every connection that goes down. How you execute your long-running task then is up to you, but basically you should schedule it on an Executor.

Comment: So, it turned out that at least part of the problem was that my `connectionStore.deleteConnection` call was timing out and I wasn't `handle`ing that properly. Once I bumped up the timeouts everything seems to be back to working as I expect.

That said, am I reading your comment correctly in that it seems like it would still be preferable to run the logic via `ctx.channel().eventLoop().execute(...)`, or is the fact that it's all asynchronous already enough (it's running in Lettuce's executor, or the AWS sdk's executor, etc.)?

Comment: I was basically only suggesting that you should offload it from the `EventLoop` if its long-running. So `ctx.channel().eventLoop().execute(...)` is not the right thing to do as this would still run on the `EventLoop`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I should be good then now that I've got timeouts fixed and am properly handling those failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed above in the comments, this had nothing to do w/ how I was handling the long running work, but instead was the lack of error handling on my futures.

Remember to always catch exceptions from your futures, kids!